# How to work on two npm packages at the same time?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I'm trying to write an npm package that will be published and used as a framework in other projects. The problem is -- I can't figure out a solid workflow for working on it at the same time as working on projects that *depend* on it.

I know this seems super basic and that `npm link` solves the issue, but this is a bigger one than just being able to import one local package from another.

I have my framework package scaffolded out; let's call it `gumby`, It exports a function that does `console.log('hello from gumby')`. That's all that matters for right now.

Now I'm ready to create a project that will use `gumby`. Let's call this one `client`. I set that up too and `npm link gumby` so `client` can import from it, etc. OK cool, it's working as expected.

So now it's time to publish `gumby`. I run `npm publish` and it goes out to npm as version 0.0.1.

At this point, how do I get the published, npm-hosted version of `gumby` into the `package.json` for `client`? I mean, I could just delete the symlinked copy from my `node_modules` and then `yarn add gumby`, but what if I want to go back and work on it locally again? And then run it against the npm version again? And then work on it some more? And then...

You get the point, I imagine. There's no obvious way to switch between the npm copy of a package that you're working on, and the local one. There's the additional problem of how to do that without messing with your `package.json` too much, e.g. what if I accidentally commit to it version control with some weird `file://` dependency path. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For local development, having the package symlinked is definitely the way to go, the idea of constantly publishing / re-installing the package sounds like a total pain.

The real issue sounds more like you’re concerned about committing a dev configuration to prod - you could address that problem with something as simple as a pre-commit hook on your VCS e.g. block if it detects any local file references in the package.json.